# How to perform morphology analysis in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking for ways to turn single words to their infinitives inside models:

```
cats -> cat
sharpest -> sharp
etc.
```

Do you know of any gems or libraries that are able to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String#singularize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/singularize) is providing : The reverse of pluralize, returns the singular form of a word in a string.

```
'posts'.singularize            # => "post"
'octopi'.singularize           # => "octopus"
'sheep'.singularize            # => "sheep"
'word'.singularize             # => "word"
'the blue mailmen'.singularize # => "the blue mailman"
'CamelOctopi'.singularize      # => "CamelOctopus"
'leyes'.singularize(:es)       # => "ley"
```

for [String#pluralize](http://apidock.com/rails/String/pluralize) : Returns the plural form of the word in the string.

```
'post'.pluralize             # => "posts"
'octopus'.pluralize          # => "octopi"
'sheep'.pluralize            # => "sheep"
'words'.pluralize            # => "words"
'the blue mailman'.pluralize # => "the blue mailmen"
'CamelOctopus'.pluralize     # => "CamelOctopi"
'apple'.pluralize(1)         # => "apple"
'apple'.pluralize(2)         # => "apples"
'ley'.pluralize(:es)         # => "leyes"
'ley'.pluralize(1, :es)      # => "ley"
```

In addition you can also have a look at ['verbs' gem](https://github.com/rossmeissl/verbs)

> Conjugates most common english verbs for all persons, tenses, standard
>   aspects, and modern moods (with active diathesis). Standard and
>   exceptional spelling rules are obeyed.

Comment: Worth pointing out that these methods are provided by rails's `ActiveSupport` and are not part of core ruby's `String` class.

Comment: Thanks... It's removed

Comment: @DeG : I m glad to help you. You can accept the answer as answered if it helps you to solve your problem.